# How to construct the document-topic matrix using the word-topic and topic-word matrix calculated using Latent Dirichlet Allocation?

Tags: python, apache-spark, lda

How to construct the document-topic matrix using the word-topic and topic-word matrix calculated using Latent Dirichlet Allocation?
I can not seem to find it anywhere, even not from the author of LDA, M.Blei.

Gensim and sklearn just work, but I want to know how to use the two matrices to construct the document topic-matrix (Spark MLLIB LDA only gives me the 2 matrices and not the document-topic matrix).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072449/extract-document-topic-matrix-from-pyspark-lda-model

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I found that and implemented that. But I want to learn the theory and implement it for my Python friends.

Answer (score 0):

> using the word-topic and topic-word matrix

This would be the same, wouldn't it? The model generates a words x topics and a topics x documents matrix, there is not much left to calculate, the model practically spits it out.

Using the Gibbs method gives you the counts Ntw[1..T][1..W] and Ndt[1..D][1..T], where for example Ndt[1][5] is the amount of words assigned to topic number 5 in document number 1.